# Is there a way to repeatedly apply filter conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql

suppose I have a single table containing a (non-unique) ID column and a number of columns containing properties.

| ID | Property A | Property B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | ABC |
| 2 | XYZ | DEF |
| 2 | RST | DEF |
| 2 | XYZ | GHI |
| 2 | UVW | GHI |
| 2 | UVW | GHI |

I want to filter out rows based on several "group by" conditions on the property columns. These conditions have the form: "keep all rows storing a duplicate property in one of the columns", in other words:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE T1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2."Property column" = T1."Property column") >= 2
```

If "Property column" = "Property B" in the above example, the rows 2-6 would be returned.

If I want to apply several of these rules, a possible solution would be to just apply them iteratively, using one WITH subquery for each rule. If we first applied this rule with Property B (keeping rows 2-6) and then with Property A, the 2nd, 4th, 5th and 6th row would be contained in the end result:

| ID | Property A | Property B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | XYZ | DEF |
| 2 | XYZ | GHI |
| 2 | UVW | GHI |
| 2 | UVW | GHI |

However, the first row of this table would then violate the "Property B" rule since there are no other rows with ID = '2' and Property B = 'DEF'. I would like both rules to be re-applied until the end table doesn't change anymore.

Is there any way to do this or an equivalent solution?

Comment: So, to make sure this is understood, you want to start by selected rows from column ID that have duplicates. Then you want the rows from query 1 that have duplicate rows in column Property A. Then you want to select rows from column Property B where there are duplicates. The end result being you want to select for all non-unique rows in your table? This is a good place for some self joins against a row_numbered CTE instead of counting.

Comment: It might be a good idea to create a stored procedure that performs a loop with a condition to stop

Comment: In the above example, I'd like to repeatedly run the SQL statement `SELECT * FROM TABLE T1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2."Property column" = T1."Property column") >= 2` for a given sequence of property columns (in my example, I'd like to start with Property B and then proceed with Property A), where TABLE is the result of the last SQL query, until no rows were dropped for an entire "column cycle". In the above example, only the last two rows should not be filtered out.

Comment: Can you edit your OP and add a table that shows exactly what your intended output based on your given dataset @Nicolas?

Comment: Is your desired end result to have all rows where (within the scope of a single ID value) the Property A value has duplicates and Property B value has duplicates? It sounds like you could query for duplicate (ID, Property A) combinations using `GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2`, query for duplicate (ID, Property B) combinations, and then join the preceding as subqueries back to the original table.

Comment: It would also help if you add a tag for your specific DBMS, such as [sql-server], [oracle], [mysql], etc. You will reach a larger audience including those who specialize in the specific DBMS you are working on, and have a better chance of getting answers that work for your DBMS.